# Assertion Error upon using model.fit() in tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm a newbie to Tensorflow-gpu. I am working on a large dataset (~30 million rows in train data, 16 million rows each in valid and test data). I'm trying to build an LSTM Autoencoder model to make time series prediction on this dataset. I've followed the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras) in the Tensorflow documentation to distribute my model across available GPUs using MirroredStrategy with HierarchicalCopyAllReduce as follows:

```
with strategy.scope():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (timesteps, features), return_sequences = True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = False),
        tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(timesteps),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True),
        tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax'))
    ])

    model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

When I try to fit the model using the following code, I get the following assertion error:

```
model.fit(X_train_tf, y_train_tf, epochs = 12, validation_data = (X_valid_tf, y_valid_tf), verbose = 1, callbacks=callbacks)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-96b3da4e4eff> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train_tf, y_train_tf, epochs = 12, validation_data = (X_valid_tf, y_valid_tf), verbose = 1, callbacks=callbacks)

~/.conda/envs/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    783         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    784         workers=workers,
--> 785         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    786 
    787   def evaluate(self,

~/.conda/envs/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_distributed.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    617         validation_split=validation_split,
    618         shuffle=shuffle,
--> 619         epochs=epochs)
    620     if not dist_utils.is_distributing_by_cloning(model):
    621       with model._distribution_strategy.scope():

~/.conda/envs/user/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v1.py in _distribution_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, validation_split, shuffle, epochs, allow_partial_batch)
   2165         x = ds.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=drop_remainder)
   2166       else:
-> 2167         assert isinstance(x, dataset_ops.DatasetV2)
   2168         training_utils.validate_dataset_input(x, y, sample_weight,
   2169                                               validation_split)

AssertionError:
```

Why is this error arising and how should I resolve it?

I'm using Tensorflow version 2.2.0-dev20200308 and Keras version 2.3.1. My train, test and validation data are of tensor type.

Thanks in advance!